# Green's functions for composite fermions

Tags: condensed-matter, many-body, greens-functions

In a regular fermionic system (such as a Fermi liquid), the Green's function is given by

$$ G({\bf k},\,\omega)=\frac{1}{\omega-\epsilon_k-\Sigma-i\delta}$$

where $\Sigma$ is the fermionic self-energy. My question is can we write the Green's functions for [composite fermions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_fermion) at arbitrary filling factor $\nu$ in a similar fashion? Would it take the above form, but the self energy take on some non-trivial value? I've tried to survey the literature, and I could not find anything useful. Any explanation or contemporary papers that answer the previous questions would be greatly appreciated.